# Pound sticky sessions between HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: load-balancing, pound

I have pound setup for http and https, and have sticky sessions based on cookie for both.

However, sessions are not sticky when jumping from http to https. Is there anyway to do this in Pound?

It's essential for my web app that stickiness is enforced between http and https.

ANSWER:

Bit of a newbie issue - I had backends defined per Service, instead of same backends for all services.